# how to filter the abnormal temperature and humidity sensor values

Tags: kalman-filter, pykalman

The temperature and humidity sensors get abnormal values like 80 degree from time to time.

How to filter the abnormal temperature and humidity sensor values? Is Kalman filtering the solution to filter out the abnormal values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe enough about your application to indicate if a Kalman filter is really called for.  However you end up filtering your data, however, you will likely need to do some filtering for the data outliers which you describe.  There is a large universe of Robust techniques such as Trimmed Mean, Median Absolute Deviation, Least Median Of Squares (LMedS), and so forth.  [This](https://www.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Lehrstuehle/MSind/SFB_475/C/2004_-_Gather_Fried-_methods_and_algorithms_for_robust_filtering.pdf) document provides a good summary of those methods.

Also, [Learning an Outlier-Robust Kalman Filter](http://www-clmc.usc.edu/publications/T/ting-ECML2007.pdf) provides a good example of robust techniques used within a Kalman Filter which seems more in line with your question.  I have used adaptations of this technique quite successfully in applications.